# Is it possible to add a "one-off" custom extrinsic without adding a new pallet?

Tags: pallet

I'd like to still have things like benchmarking but since the feature is one extrinsic, doesn't need new storage, etc. a pallet feels overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we provide no way to add a call that is not part of a pallet. However, writing a bare minimum pallet isn't that big :)